# Android: How to use screen orientation change to switch between activities

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I'm new to Android development. I'm trying to use the orientation change to switch between two activities. My idea is to use three Activities one TabActivity and a normal Activity. Here is some pseudo code:

```
public class Main extends Activity{
// this is the entry point into my app
    @Override
    public void onCreate(...){
        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            // Start Activity1
    } else { //Start Activity2}
}
```

The Activities Activity1 and Activity2 will have their onPause() functions overridden with an intent to start the Main Activity again.

```
onPause(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.ActivityX, Main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

\/\/\/\/ EDIT \/\/\/\/

Ok, I'm taking a different approach. As i need a TabActivity, because i want to be able to start different activities in my tabs (I think i have to use a TabActivity in this case).

I've edited the Manifest.xml and added android.configChanges="orientation" for the TabActivity and the second Activity. Then I've overridden the onConfigurationChanged() functions. With this approach I'm able to switch from landscape (this is the "normal" activity") to portrait (the TabActivity).
The other way round does not work and i don't know why yet. I've exactly the same onConfigurationChanged functions (Copy & Pasted) and only changed the essential parts.

Overriding the onConfigurationChanged of the Activities started in the tabs has no effect, too.

Comment: Why would you switch entire activities on orientation change instead of just switching layouts?

Comment: In landscape i would like to show a graphic, where you can select pictures. And i want to show the corresponding data in a tab in portrait view. And the tabbed View needs a TabActivity.

Comment: @mbaird: Please note that when orientation changes current activity gets killed and a new one is created. Log at `onDestroy` and `onCreate` to see this happen.

Comment: @Darokthar: You do not need `TabActivity` to use tabs. Please do not switch entire activities on orientation changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare: my experience is that activities get automatically killed and recreated (even if it's the same class) when orientation change happens. Then using different activities for portrait & landscape should not be that expensive? Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: @Peter Knego: No, it is twice as expensive. Android destroys the activity, creates the wrong activity, creates the right activity, and destroys the wrong activity. Please do not switch entire activities on orientation changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare: If I understand correctly - you advocate only against programmatically switching activities on orientation change, but not to resource switching approach described below in the answer?

Comment: The way i described above does indeed recreates the wrong activity first. At the moment i don't know, if it is possible to avoid this behavior. If the orientation changes the framework will automatically restart the running activity. Therefore he is not recommending it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to write any code - Android already [handles this automatically](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility). Just create two different layout resource folders:

```
/res/layout-land  // layout resources for landscape
/res/layout-port  // portrait layout
```

Put in this folders `xyz.xml` resource description files with the same name and different content. One using activities for portrait, the other for landscape.

Note that you can use the same technique (`-port` & `-land` qualifiers) for drawables (bitmaps) or any other resources (text).

**Note:** this is not supported on Android 1.5. If you want to support this version you must additionally add the `/res/layout` folder.

Comment: I know about that. But i don't know how to start an activity out of a layout file. The normal way is to load the layout at runtime with setContentView(). But as one activity is tabbed and thus a TabActivity even this won't work, as TabActivity has no setContentView() function. I guess my problem is the TabActivity. Maybe it is possible in the Manifest.xml file to make two entry points, one for portrait and one for landscape?

Comment: Look @CommonsWare comment above: you do not need TabActivity to create tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the advantages of TabActivity when using tabs in portrait mode, while not having tabs in landscape mode, you could use the following (ugly but still working) workaround. Create /res/layout-land folder and put there a corresponding layout file (it should have the same name that the file in layout folder, you use for portrait orientation). This file, however, should contain the blocks required by the TabActivity to work. That is fine, add those blocks and set their visibility to "gone", like in the following snippet:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <!-- Feel free to add your REAL layout for the landscape -->
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Of course, make sure you handle the content management correctly in your activity class, depending on the orientation.